# Four Part Name User Control Web Part-SP 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a user control and tested it by adding it to the aspx page, it works very well.

I wrote the user control, so that I can use in my Sharepoint Portal.

I have created a sharepoint webpart project and added the following code to the method.

```
public class Nov059PM : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
{
    Control _myControl;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();

        _myControl = this.Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrols/Grid.ascx");

        this.Controls.Add(_myControl);
    }
}
```

I have placed the Grid.ascx in the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\myportno\usercontrols folder.

I have built the webpart and deployed it.

When I try to use it, it says:

> Could not load type 'Grid.Grid'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Grid.Grid" %>

I am thinking, Inherits should be four part name.  How do I generate four part name for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deployed the `.ascx` file but forgot the assembly or the code-behind file that contains the `Grid.Grid` class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add fully assembly version in

**<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Grid.Grid,Grid,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=*PUBKEYTOKEN*"    %>**

And put Grid.dll in GAC.

before that you have to apply SNK in Grid.dll.